# react native icon not displaying using react-native-ionicons and material-bottom-tabs ( displaying with a cross )

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and was trying to develop a simple screen with a header a footer and some icons on the footer
Here is my abbreviated code :

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons';

const BottomNavigator = () => {
return (
  <BottomTab.Navigator>
  <BottomTab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
  tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
    <Icon ios="ios-addx" android="md-addx"  color={color} size={size} />
  )
  }}/>
  <BottomTab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{
  tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
    <Icon name="home"  size={size} color={color} />
  )
}}/>
</BottomTab.Navigator>
);
}
```

This is what shows up :
[image]

Reading various answers on SO - most of them seem to be related to 'react native vector icons' while I am using 'react native ionicons'

Tried to link using the following command :

```
react-native link react-native-ionicons
```

However I get the error :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there add this line top in file android/app/build.gradle and `react-native run-android` again

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Comment: thanks for the help yesterday , but one issue I am observing is that the icons that show up are wierd , for 'Home' a completely different icon shows up not sure why ... `<Icon name="brush" />` does not show a brush icon its some different icon ...

Comment: you have invalid import of Icon you have to do like this import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons' and then you have to visit vector icons website to get name of material icons name to give <Icon name=""/> Tag

Comment: And you can also import individually like if you want to use FontAwesome you can import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome' and u can use <FontAwesome name=""/>

Comment: thank you excellent answers yes you are correct ! once again thank you , 'shukriya' as well as 'dhanyavaad' :)